# Will a Gnome 4 snap run with Gnome 3?

Tags: gnome, snap, eog

I want to try a more recent image viewer, Eye Of Gnome (eog) version 4. My computer is running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS which uses Gnome version 3.

I removed eog 3.36.3 using

```
sudo apt remove eog
```

and installed version 40.2 using

```
sudo snap install eog
```

`snap list` now tells me I have:

```
eog   40.2     602  latest/stable  canonical✓  -
```

Sadly this snap install of eog doesn't work. In /var/log/syslog I see the following errors:

```
Sep 25 01:43:57 vw-dell zeitgeist-datah[7664]: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:210: Error during inserting events: GDBus.Error:org.gnome.zeitgeist.EngineError.InvalidArgument: Incomplete event: interpretation, manifestation and actor are required
Sep 25 01:43:57 vw-dell systemd[1874]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
Sep 25 01:43:57 vw-dell systemd[1874]: Started snap.eog.eog.25cc936e-2a05-4797-9de9-19c76cb0466a.scope.
Sep 25 01:43:57 vw-dell systemd[1874]: gnome-launched-eog_eog.desktop-8683.scope: Succeeded.
Sep 25 01:43:57 vw-dell eog_eog.desktop[8683]: /snap/eog/602/usr/bin/eog: error while loading shared libraries: libportal.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Sep 25 01:43:57 vw-dell systemd[1874]: snap.eog.eog.25cc936e-2a05-4797-9de9-19c76cb0466a.scope: Succeeded.
```

Is Snap meant to enable this recent version of eog to run under Ubuntu 20.04 ?

Later edit. Following the suggestion by user535733 I have raised the following issue:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/eog/-/issues/211

Comment: Please file a bug report with the Snap authors: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/eog/-/issues

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the snap, where its dependences and other dependent snaps are not available or properly configured.  File a bug on the snap as indicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general answer to your question is: "**Yes, a Gnome 4 snap should run with Gnome 3**". *Any* snap should run on *any* linux system that supports snap. That is what the snap system is designed for.

This is at the core of these containerized application formats. They run in a sandbox, using their own libraries - or common libraries provided by other snap packages (the so-called "stage-snaps") that then should have been automatically installed with the snap, if not yet available.

What you are facing here is a defect snap package. Apparently it was published without sufficient testing.

Answer (score 1):

#### Tl;dr

This was probably a failed attempt at porting. Search the other channels of the same package for newer versions. If it is new, there is likely a nightly build, although I doubt you found this on `stable`. Check Flatpak for the same package. Chances are you will find it.

#### Conclusion

It looks to me like you have a broken package? It is failing because it cannot find a shared library that it needs.

So technically, the answer is:

*you need the file* `libportal.so`

however,

1. The fact that it is not included with `eog` or wrapped in  package in apt is strange
2. After a bit of research, it looks like the library is part of the `flatpak` API. In fact, the flatpak sandbox abstraction is sometimes called the "portal".

I am not a flatpak developer by any stretch, but I know enough to know that the sandbox implementations are way different to share APIs.

My guess is that the package was recently ported from flatpak, and there is a discrepancy somewhere in the metadata for the package.

The gook news is that it is most likely available on `Flatpak`! Although if the app needs any significant permissions - i.e. access to the OS's devices or other global resources - to run, you will soon know what those differences I mentioned all too well.

Comment: Is this then another illustration of the sometimes poor quality of snap packages? It occurs quite frequently that a snap "doesn't work". In principle, a snap with software from Gnome 40 should indeed work without problem on any system that supports snap.

Comment: They may have used a pkg2pkg type converter, and didn't check the result. There seem to be a lot of those floating around nowadays. Some are probably better than others. Regardless, I wouldn't put anything out there without knowing exactly what it was. Standing on the shoulders of giants.. with bad backs.